# How to replicate AWS AMI on our local Ubuntu servers?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ami

I have Titan X server (Ubuntu 16.04) and I want to get it something similar to AWS Deep Learning AMI (Conda env for PyTorch and tensorflow).

Comment: Have you read this documentation : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vm-import/latest/userguide/what-is-vmimport.html

Comment: @KushVyas Vikram wants to copy an official AWS AMI. VM Export only works for images that were previously imported.

Comment: Oh I get it now sorry my bad :)

Comment: @vikram-garg This is not officially supported. You can install all the software manually or try your luck cloning the volume: https://weaponshot.wordpress.com/2012/04/08/downloading-an-ami-to-local/

Comment: Guys. I am sorry but probably i was not clear. I don't want to "copy" anything. Just looking for steps to install Conda env for PyTorch and tensorflow on my machine. AWS AMI for deep learning is very good and I just want to replicate something similar on my machine. Further I am not looking for docker solutions :)